# Is there a preferred file format for importing data into Tableau?

Tags: r, csv, tableau-api

I am working with some tabular data in R and need to import it into Tableau.

I can export the data in a variety of file formats (e.g., csv, .xlsx, .rda, etc.), but I'm wondering if there is a *preferred* file format from the perspective of successfully reading data into Tableau.

For example, when I export a dataset with missing values from R to a csv it codes the missing values as `"NA"` character strings. Tableau then misinterprets these columns as character columns. I can avoid this error by re-coding missing values in R as `NULL` values, but this experience got me wondering if there is a particular file format that Tableau imports most seamlessly.

Or should I export the data from R into the Tableau Data Extract (`.tde`) using the [`rtableau`](https://github.com/markahayden/rtableau) package?

---

**EDIT:** Unfortunately for me, [`rtableau`](https://github.com/markahayden/rtableau) is only compatible with [Linux and Mac systems](https://github.com/markahayden/rtableau/blob/master/README.md#set-up) and does not appear to be actively maintained.

Connecting Tableau to a `.rda` via the **`Connect`** > **`Statistical File`** interface may be the best approach (more info [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_statfile.html#Rdata)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don‘t have a definitive answer for you, but I have worked on several projects involving both R and Tableau. I recommend using the package to create `.tde` Files, since this forces you to format the data in the native types provided by Tableau and should lead to the least error-prone work-flows.

Ingesting `csv` in Tableau has multiple possibilities of failure. Apart from those you mentioned, I once ran into the problem that Tableau chooses the column type based on the first 500 observations. Thus, depending on the data, one specific column was either identified as „numeric“ or as „integer“, leading to errors in the visualization. Similar problems exist with all non-native data types, in my experience.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your response is very helpful - thank you! I'm going to leave the question open for a while to see if there are other perspectives, but I think it's likely that the answer you provided is as good as it's going to get.

Comment: When Tableau misinterprets the data type of a column, you can always change it manually. So this isn't usually a critical problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it really matters. There are certainly performance differences between an Excel/CSV and a Tableau Data Extract. Either way, you can create an extract after the fact. I would suggest to use what ever reduces your data prep once you connect to Tableau. Do as much as you can before hand. Always improves performance of you dashboards.